# option data-value not showing

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have this code where I want to show different pricing with different values when selected on the drop down. But my code has an error ang it doesn't show the output when I added "data-value"

Hope someone can help me with this thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Select your pricing on different location</p>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="$1,000" data-value="$2,000">Price 1</option>
  <option value="$2,000" data-value="$3,000">Price 2</option>
  <option value="$3,000" data-value="$4,000">Price 3</option>
  <option value="$4,000" data-value="$5,000">Price 4</option>
</select>

<p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>

<p id="pricing"></p>
<p id="pricing-value"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("mySelect").data-value;
  document.getElementById("pricing").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
  document.getElementById("pricing-value").innerHTML = y + " VALUE ";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't show the output when I added the data-value

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes.  Also, it's not the select that has the data attribute, it's the options.  You can get the selected option from `select.options[select.selectedIndex]`

Comment: I have replaced data-value to data-pricing I also move the <script> tag before the code and it works, but it return the value of y as NaN

Comment: data-value is interpreted as data minus value, which is not a number (NaN).  See the link on how to get the data-value.

Comment: sorry I am a beginner with coding so in my understanding since the value showed up data-pricing should be showing too...

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to accomplish this is to attach the onchange listener in your javascript to get the event.

```
var selection = document. querySelector("#mySelect");

selection.onchange = function(event) {
  var selectedValue = event.target.value;
  var dataValue = event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].dataset.value;
  document. querySelector("#pricing").innerHTML = "You selected: " + selectedValue;
  document. querySelector("#pricing-value").innerHTML = dataValue + " VALUE ";
 };
```

Comment: Thank you it worked it finally showed the data-value. But I noticed that when you click the Pricing 2 it doesn't showed the content but if you will go back to Pricing 1 content will show up.

Comment: I changed the onchange to onclick so it's working now. Thank you for your help :)